# Updating MySQL table, deleting old records. 

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have an associative MySQL table (user_category) that stores users preferneces for categories. It has a UserId column and a CategoryCode column. If a user was interested in the travel(trvl) category and the free stuff(free)category then the record would look like this.

```
UserId    CategoryCode
1         trvl
1         free
```

What is the best way to update this record when the user updates their category preferences?
I thought the easiest way would be to just

```
DELETE FROM user_category WHERE UserId = 1;
INSERT INTO user_category (UserId,CategoryCode) VALUES (1,'catx'),(1,'catx'),(1,'catx')
```

Where 'catx' are the new categories that they are interested in.

Comment: Is there an option to add a primary key to the table?  You could then update the table setting an id field.  Then you can manipulate individual records.  While it would take a little more up front effort, your data management would be a lot easier.

Comment: @dmcnelis There is a primary key. PRIMARY KEY(UserId,CategoryCode). -1 for suggesting that I denormalize my table unnnecesarily.

Answer (score 5):

Some times easiest solutions are the best ones. And this is one of this times ;)

Comment: hmm good point. My only concern would be if the query failed and I deleted the records but did not update. I do agree though my solution is probably the best one. I sometimes ask this sort of question in the hopes that I will be introduced to some new and interesting type of mysql that I have never seen before.

Comment: Downside: unnecessary deletes in InnoDB will cause some notable overhead, and in MyISAM will still create an increased load and scattering of values.

Comment: @andrew: however, if you have InnoDB and are performing everything in a transaction (highly recommended), either method will work to the same ultimate effect.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation. If you can put the new selection a Table structure, this query allows you to delete just de preferences that are no longer valid and insert just the new preferences. It also works if you need to operate batch for many users at the same time.

```
-- Delete just the preferences that are no longer valid
DELETE  user_category 
from    user_category a left join
        NewSelection b on a.UserId=b.UserId and a.CategoryCode=b.CategoryCode
WHERE   b.CategoryCode is null

-- Insert just the new preferences
INSERT INTO user_category (UserId,CategoryCode) 
SELECT  a.UserId,a.CategoryCode
FROM    NewSelection a left join
        user_category b on a.UserId=b.UserId and a.CategoryCode=b.CategoryCode
where   b.CategoryCode is null
```

Comment: +1 for providing a interesting take on this problem. For very large tables I assume that it is most efficient to delete only those that need updating and insert only those that need inserting as this query would allow. Could be completely wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from user_category where UserId = 1 and CategoryCode not in (x, y, z)
insert into user_category values (1, x) on duplicate key update CategoryCode = x
```

Assume that your primary key is UserId, CategoryCode.

Comment: The UserId is not the primary key, since the sample records the OP provided allow multiple rows for that user.

Comment: But it would be better if there was an 'ON DUPLICATE KEY do nothing' if it exists.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister he explicitly says assume that the primary key is (UserId,CategoryCode) not UserId

Comment: @andrew 1) i believe the answer was edited, and 2) the `on duplicate key update` is doing nothing useful. use `INSERT IGNORE` instead.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: There are no edits recorded to this answer. There is a benefit to not using insert ignore... ignore turns errors to warnings, and that still causes warnings. I would presume that the performance of an ineffective update, an ignore, and an ineffective replace should be equal.